# Duplicating values in Datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I am inserting values to Mysqldb via Selected row. Inserting into Mysqldb was successful

**Problem**: when i load the values that ive inserted in Mysqldb into another Datagridview, the Values is Duplicating 9x. but when i check it in the Mysql db it does not Duplicate.

```
     Dim MysqlConn3 As New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn3.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Gaezlevister214;database=librarydb;"
    Dim command3 As New MySqlCommand
    Dim SDA3 As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bSource3 As New BindingSource
    Dim dbDataSet3 As New DataTable
    Try
        MysqlConn3.Open()
        Dim Query3 As String
        Query3 = "Select blist.quantity as 'Qty', returnedlist.student_id as 'Student ID', returnedlist.call_number as 'Call_Number',returnedlist.date_added as 'Date Borrowed',returnedlist.due_date as 'Due Date' from librarydb.returnedlist, librarydb.blist"
        command3 = New MySqlCommand(Query3, MysqlConn3)
        SDA3.SelectCommand = command3
        SDA3.Fill(dbDataSet3)
        bSource3.DataSource = dbDataSet3
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource3
        SDA3.Update(dbDataSet3)

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally

        MysqlConn3.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: **Problem:** No code.  See [Ask]

Comment: sir what part of the code you want to see? the formload of the values? or the inserting into db?

Comment: I would guess that we would want to see the code that is causing you to receive 9x duplicate rows in your datagridview since that seems to be an issue.

Comment: In the load event sir?

Comment: You've confirmed there are no duplicates in the db, so it shouldn't be the insert. Therefore, we need to see the code that gets the data and possibly the code populating the DataGridView.

Comment: I have inserted the code of Loading the Data to a Datagridview

Comment: @Deo Sounds you're a noob starter. If you mean you doubleclicked on a datagridview and enter these codes there the codes will be executed on default event of datagridview which wil cause these codes to be called once per click on datagridview. Try to place a button in your form and move these codes on button click event.

Comment: You need to have greater vision and understandings about BindingSources, DataSources, SqlCommands and Connection objects and event handling.